# PySpark and HIVE/Impala

Tags: hive, pyspark, logistic-regression, impala

I want to build a classification model in PySpark. My input to this model is result of select query or view from Hive or Impala. is any way to include this query in PySpark code itself instead of storing result in text file feeding to our model

Answer (score 1):

Yes for this you need to use HiveContext with sparkContext.
Here is example:-

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
tableData = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
#tableData is a dataframe containing reference to schema of table, check this using tableData.printSchema()
tableData.collect() #collect executes query and provide all rows from sql
```

or you may refer here
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. so tableData will be my input data to model right? my whole aim is to once i run pyspark logit regression code on daily basis my regression model should work and data to my model should include latest updated records in my data set (train and test)

Comment: @RRAMESHNAIK yes table data will be direct input to your model.

Comment: Thank u so much Rakesh. one more thing is we must convert our data as RDD right . so the result of tableData.collect() is a raw data or its already a RDD. i mean should convert it as RDD ?

Comment: @RRAMESHNAIK you can convert it to  rdd like tableData.rdd

Comment: but, how do you provide the credential for connecting the impala in pyspark?

Comment: @AjayTanpure check this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases, it will help you